# JQuery - remove cssObject after adding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I do this:

```
var cssObject = {
                'background-color' : '#042c59',
                '-moz-box-shadow' : '0 0 22px #111',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0 0 22px #111',
                'box-shadow' : '0 0 22px #111'
            }

                $('#mydiv').css(cssObject);
            }
```

I can't seem to figure out how to remove that same cssObject from mydiv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are not adding a css object, you are adding a map that jquery interprets and sets the css values on the objects selected. If you want to toggle css style easily, I recommend addClass, removeClass, or toggleClass.

```
.selected{
background-color : #042c59,
-moz-box-shadow : 0 0 22px #111,
-webkit-box-shadow : 0 0 22px #111,
box-shadow : '0 0 22px #111
}

$('#mydiv').toggleClass("selected");
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Definitely what you should do. I never add styles directly. I always add a semantic class and define its "look" through CSS.

Comment: There is also a speed improvement in this approach because you are only modifying the "className" object instead of multiple "style" object modifications (in this case, 4).

Comment: @David: I disagree. Modifying the className causes all the cascading rules to be recalculated while modifying the style disregards any cascading rules. The most proper way to do things is not usually the fastest. I've been part of a project where we switched to styles directly because all the modifications to classNames were much slower (with speed tests so we didn't go into regression in the future). I'd love to have you prove me wrong with a speed test.

Comment: @Juan I stand corrected - there's no guaranteed improvement as I implied. I'm curious to know more about the speed tests; were you testing the browser re-drawing elements?

Comment: @David: It was a timesheet. We applied lots of classes to each of the cells (entries) to represent the state of the cell: active, dirty-unsaved, default-value, picked-from-a-list and any others. However, when dealing with monthly timesheets, where we could have up to 450 rows, with 6-10 cells each, applying styles directly cut down the time to almost half. Yes, we were testing how fast it took the browser to apply the changes to the UI, not just how long it takes to set a string value on a node's attribute :p

Comment: Forgot one detail, after we stopped supporting IE6, we moved back to css classes, we just ensure that we don't manipulate `node.className` a bunch of times. We gather all the classes that we have to remove and add and we add/remove them in one shot.